# K means clustering ml library using apache spark

Tags: apache-spark, k-means

I am trying to implement k means clustering using apache spark ml version in 2.0.2. After finding the cluster center , facing the issue in how do identity the data belongs to which cluster point. Please help me.. Thanks in advance. Please find my code :

val tokenFrameprocess = TokenizerProcessor.process("value", "tokenized")

```
val stopwordRemover = StopWordsProcessor.process("tokenized", "stopwords")

val stemmingProcess = StemmingProcessor.process("value", "stemmed")

val HashingProcess = HashingTFProcessor.process("stopwords" ,"features")




 val pipeline = new Pipeline().setStages(Array(tokenFrameprocess,stopwordRemover,stemmingProcess,HashingProcess))


val finalFrameProcess = pipeline.fit(df)

val finalFramedata = finalFrameProcess.transform(df);




val kmeans = new KMeans().setK(4).setSeed(1L)

val model = kmeans.fit(finalFramedata)




val WSSSE = model.computeCost(finalFramedata)

   // Shows the result.
println("Cluster Centers: ")

model.clusterCenters.foreach(println)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set the feature column which will be used to predict on while instantiating the Kmeans like following example:

```
val kmeans = new KMeans().setK(4).setSeed(1L).setFeaturesCol("features").setPredictionCol("prediction")
```

Once you call the .fit() on the kmeans, It returns a [Transformer](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.0-preview/ml-guide.html#transformers). In case of your example, variable "model" is a transformer. You can call the .transform() To get the desired prediction on the given data. For example below lines will give you the dataframe with prediction column.

```
val model = kmeans.fit(finalFramedata)
val transformedDF = model.transform(finalFramedata)
transformedDF.show(false)
```

Prediction column denotes clusters points. If you give k value as 3 and the prediction column will have values like 0,1,2.

Comment: @rathika Answer to your question "Is prediction column denotes clusters point ? i am giving k value as 3 and prediction column having values like 0,1,2." Is yes. The prediction column value denotes the cluster centre which belongs to the particular data point and it starts with "0". So If you've provided 3 cluster centres, There will be only three values i.e. 0,1,2 in the prediction column.